# directory browsing within webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, perl, directory

I would like to give the user a file browser from within a webpage.

Here is what I've tried.  I'm trying to present the file contents myself.  I am trying to make it so there is div that is the same as what you would get on an ordinary directory browse within the webpage.  I have succeeded in making the div work visually, displaying the contents of the selected folder but when trying to click on a file in that directory it can not find the file because it is looking in the wrong file path `index.html/` instead of `index.html/videos`.

Code:

```
<div id="new-nav"></div>

<script>
  $("#new-nav").load("/videos");
</script>
```

What's the best way to give the user a "file browser" experience in a webpage?

Comment: Why not just use an iframe instead? Unless your generated directory lists contain absolute urls, the browser is going to make them relative to the page that the div is in, not the url you used to load the listing from. Using an iframe gets around that, since it'll be its own distinct little document and have its own base url.

Comment: wow ive been trying to get this to work for hours and this worked in 20 seconds, this is great! Thank you! what the best way to choose the size of the iframe?

Comment: like this `<iframe height="200" width="200"`

Comment: wow thanks, this is my first post on this site and im just getting started learning more indepth code in various languages and this is by far the best community for help. Thank you is there a way to give reputation for your help or something?

Comment: You can ask @MarcB to put his comment as an answer and accept that as that solved your problem. You can also upvote any comment or answers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using http://ckfinder.com/demo instead.

Features of CkFinder as Listed on their Site

- Lightweight interface.
- No page refreshes: quick responses.
- Folders    tree navigation: intuitive for all users.
- Quality image thumbnails,    making it quick to find things.
- Multi-language support with automatic    user language detection.
- Context-sensitive menus for files and    folders.
- Multiple file uploads with a progress bar (*).
- Full user    control of the content: create, rename, and delete
  folders and files.
- Drag-and-drop support for copying and moving files between folders.
- Full developer control: all features can be precisely configured with
  a powerful ACL and user roles system.
- Flexible configuration: store    files in private folders, also
  outside the document root.
- Secure file    uploads: all uploaded files are checked according to
  the rules set by    the developer.
- Full source code included for the server side    integration.
- Instant integration with CKEditor and FCKeditor.

Comment: this seems interesting i will have to look into it and see if it fits what im looking for thank you!